# When a user stops rotating the ship, how do I get it to smoothly rotate back?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So the question may not be clear, but the ship rotates with arrow keys perfectly, but when the arrow keys are released I want it to rotate back to the position (0, yRotation, 0) but in a smooth motion (the same motion for which the user rotates it in the first place), any idea how I can do this?

xRotation, yRotation and zRotation are all initialised to 0.

```
    float xThrow = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");


        if(xThrow > 0) {

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation +     0.6f, zRotation - 0.6f);
            yRotation += 0.6f;
            zRotation -= 0.6f;
                        }

        else if (xThrow < 0)
        {

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation -     0.6f, zRotation + 0.6f);
            yRotation -= 0.6f;
            zRotation += 0.6f;
        } 

      else {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, yRotation,     zRotation);
            while (zRotation > 0) {
              zRotation -= 0.6f;
            }

            while (zRotation < 0) {
            zRotation += 0.6f;
            }
        }
```

The code I have written takes it back to the required rotation position however it is not smooth at all and does it as a single frame. I want to achieve this, but in a very smooth motion instead of a single frame looking one.

Comment: Mayby you should use Coroutines...

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to reset the rotation in the `else` block you should use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Attention since I also guess you are using this in an `Update` method be careful to not start multiple routines.

```
// set this in the Inspector
public float resetDuration;

// make sure there is only one routine running at once
private bool isResetting;

// ...

    else 
    {
        // if no routine is running so far start one
        if(!isResetting) StartCoroutine(RotateToIdentity());
    }

// ...

private IEnumerator RotateToIdentity()
{
    isResetting = true;

    // I recommend using this for rotations and not do them by manipulating 
    // 3 float values. Otherwise could also Lerp all three float values and use them for the rotation here as well
    var currentRot = transform.localRotation;
    var targetRot = Quaternion.Identity;

    // than use those
    // var currentX = xRotation;
    // var currentY = yRotation;
    // var currentZ = zRotation;

    var timePassed = 0.0f;
    while(timePassed <= resetDuration)
    {
        // interpolate between the original rotation and the target
        // using timePassed / resetDuration as factor => a value between 0 and 1
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRot, targetRot, timePassed / resetDuration);

        // or with your rotations
        // xRotation = Mathf.Lerp(currentX, 0, timePassed / resetDuration);
        // yRotation = Mathf.Lerp(currentY, 0, timePassed / resetDuration);
        // zRotation = Mathf.Lerp(currentZ, 0, timePassed / resetDuration);
        // transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, zRotation);

        // add passed time since last frame
        timePassed += Time.deltaTtime;

        // return to the mein thread, render the frame and go on in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // finally apply the target rotation just to be sure to avoid over/under shooting
    transform.rotation = targetRot;

    // if you really want to go on using xRotation, yRotation and zRotation also reset them when done
    xRotation = 0;
    yRotation = 0;
    zRotation = 0;

    isResetting = false;
}
```

You should also really consider using [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) for all your rotations.

The one advantage of using the 3 individual lerps: as soon as the user interacts again he could interupt the reset routine

```
if(xThrow > 0) 
{   
    StopAllCoroutines();
    isResetting = false;

    // ...
}
else if (xThrow < 0)
{
    StopAllCoroutines();
    isResetting = false;

    // ...
}

// ---
```